# Deleted strings from validators still showing up in project

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, sitecore, customvalidator

I'm trying to put together a form and work within the ASP validation framework if possible. Recently it seemed prudent to re-think some of the validation and so I got rid of four validators and replaced them with one `CustomValidator`. Now I have two `CustomValidator`s (previously I had one `CustomValidator` and four `RegulorExpressionValidator`s).

So here's the weird thing. One of my custom validators was somehow showing the error messages from the validators I deleted. I've actually double checked and confirmed that the `string` it is displaying is no longer in the project. Nor is it anywhere in the directory I'm deploying to. (I've built, cleaned, and rebuilt).

Further, this did not appear to be a browser cache issue as I have the cache turned off (FF Web Developer). The problem would also change based on where I placed the validator in the page (again verifying that this was not some bizarro cache issue).

I was finally able to resolve it by content inside of the validator tag.

So this works:

```
<asp:CustomValidator
        ID="validateUrl"
        OnServerValidate="ValidateWebsiteUrl"
        ClientValidationFunction="isUrlValid" 
        ControlToValidate="websiteURLInput"
        ValidationGroup="CommentGroup"
        runat="server" 
        ForeColor="#991112"
>Please enter a valid URL</asp:CustomValidator>
```

But this fails:

```
<asp:CustomValidator
        ID="validateUrl"
        OnServerValidate="ValidateWebsiteUrl"
        ClientValidationFunction="isUrlValid" 
        ControlToValidate="websiteURLInput"
        ValidationGroup="CommentGroup"
        runat="server" 
        ForeColor="#991112"
        ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid URL" />
```

As does this (no error message):

```
<asp:CustomValidator
        ID="validateUrl"
        OnServerValidate="ValidateWebsiteUrl"
        ClientValidationFunction="isUrlValid" 
        ControlToValidate="websiteURLInput"
        ValidationGroup="CommentGroup"
        runat="server" 
        ForeColor="#991112" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A validator control has a `Text` and an `ErrorMessage` property, in normal usage the Text overrules the ErrorMessage, and the content inside the tag is the same as the Text property (like with Label.Text)

The ErrorMessage is used if no Text is specified or when a ValidationSummary is used.

I hope this helps you to find the real problem.